# Koin: getting NoBeanDefFoundException while resolving class instance in Java Activity

Tags: android, koin, android-koin

Using Koin3 for Java project. Currently I have to inject/get Koin instances in some Java Activities. But when I'm trying start an Activity with Koin injection, I get the following error: `org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class [class_name].  Check your definitions!`. Any suggestions?

Usign the same injections in Kotlin ViewModel class works good as expected.

Application:

```
KoinApplication koin = KoinAndroidApplication
        .create(this)
        .logger(new AndroidLogger())
        .modules(KoinModuleKt.getAppModule());
startKoin(koin);
```

Module:

```
val appModule = module {
    //singletons
    single <SettingsManagerInterface> { SettingsManager(androidContext()) }
    //factories
    factory <SystemServiceHelperInterface> { SystemServiceHelper(androidContext()) }
    viewModel { SettingsViewModel(get(), get()) }
}
```

Activity:

```
import static org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.get;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private final SettingsManagerInterface settingsManager = get(SettingsManager.class);
        private final SystemServiceHelperInterface serviceHelper = get(SystemServiceHelper.class);
```

Comment: Getting the same error using Lazy injection: `Lazy<SettingsManagerInterface> settingsManager = inject(SettingsManager.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the interface class with a definition in koin graph in your koin `get()` calls, e.g. chante

```
private final SettingsManagerInterface settingsManager = get(SettingsManager.class);
private final SystemServiceHelperInterface serviceHelper = get(SystemServiceHelper.class);
```

to

```
private final SettingsManagerInterface settingsManager = get(SettingsManagerInterface.class);
private final SystemServiceHelperInterface serviceHelper = get(SystemServiceHelperInterface.class);
```